# Allow only specific email address' domain to register through JQuery (preferably)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make registration form within which I want to register only with specific domains' emails. For e.g. I want to register only the emails which are from the companyX, companyY, companyZ.

Hence the acceptable emails would be:-

- myname@companyZ.com
- myname@companyY.com
- myname@companyX.com

Any idea how to do it in JQuery?

### Update

This is what I wrote, uptill now

```
($input)

if (
     (preg_match("/^\S+@companyX\.com$/i", $input) ||
     (preg_match("/^\S+@companyY\.com$/i", $input) ||
     (preg_match("/^\S+@companyZ\.com$/i", $input)
   ) {

}
else {
      //Error.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What code do you already have, and what problems do you have with it?  This isn't a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: You're going to be looking at a regex function to search for specific string matches.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Also, I'd advise that you don't come on here posting extremely vague and open ended questions that, and I'm not making accusations, imply you're looking for someone to build the code for you.  Take it from me personally, as it's happened, but you'll get downvoted to oblivion and get your account banned.

Comment: Whatever validation you do in jQuery you're going to need to replicate it server side, else it would be trivially easy for someone to hop into the Chrome dev tools or Firebug and circumvent this 'feature'.

Comment: Archer, LDJ, I've updated what I did. tPlummer, please relax. I am still learning and try to be as colloquial as possible but thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Steve - No worries, mate.  Just be careful.  Some guys on here can be jerks.  I'm not one of them. ;)

Comment: Thank you tPlummer. I know I am not clear and much technical enough (yet) but yah, I should be careful :-) and thank you for not down-voting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An email is only going to contain one @ so you could split the input value and take the second part

```
str = str.split('@').slice(1);
```

then simply check if that is in your acceptable list

```
var allowedDomains = [ 'x.com', 'y.com', 'z.com' ];

if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
    //acceptable
}else{
    //not acceptable
}
```

here is a working example in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UwmYK/2/ just type in the email and click run.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help, although LDJ is right that it might be wise to have a similar validation on the server to stop anyone by-passing the jQuery validation

Comment: And don't forget to allow for upper and lower case (and mixes of the two)

Answer (score 0):

What if you have the input textbox only accept the first part of an email address and then have a select box that only has the email domains you want to allow for the user to select from?

Comment: good idea, but I want this to be as seamless as it could be. I wonder there was a way that it automatically shows a dropdown out of textbox that only these three domains are allowed when user keys-down on the textbox.