# Validate email comes from specific domain/subdomain

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

Can someone show me how to validate that an email address comes from a certain domain/subdomain like example.com or email.example.com. If it does not come from any of these domains/subdomains then form cannot be submitted.

Here is my form html:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="mail.php">
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com" required>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Please show me how to integrate it into my form above

Thanks

This is what i tried so far:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="mail.php">
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com" required>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>

 <script>
    function IsValidEmail(email)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").submit(function() {
        var allowedDomains = [ 'x.com', 'y.com', 'z.com' ];
        if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
             //acceptable
        }else{
             //not acceptable
        }
 </script>
```

mail.php file

```
<?php
$to = $_POST["email"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.\n
Name: $name\n
Email: $to\n
Sending IP: $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
$from = "test@example.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: We don't do your work for you. Show what you have tried.

Comment: i tried this script found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617723/allow-only-specific-email-address-domain-to-register-through-jquery-preferably

Comment: but cant seem to get it to work or integrate it

Comment: The above solution is used jQuery. Have you included the jQuery in your file.

Comment: can i just save the script in a js file and then put <script src="form.js"> into my html?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors but it just cant valid that the email is correct and just submits the form

Comment: and yes i include the jQuery file @Duli

Comment: It seems that you haven't set form id. Please set form id as this <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="mail.php">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i tried this script found at [Allow only specific email address' domain to register through JQuery (preferably)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617723)

However, you forgot the most relevant part: Getting the part after the `@` sign and testing *that* against the array. The `str[0]` you're currently using is still undefined.

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var allowedDomains = [ 'x.com', 'y.com', 'z.com' ];
    var domain = $("#email").val().split("@")[1];
    if ($.inArray(domain, allowedDomains) !== -1) {
        //acceptable, do nothing
    } else{
        //not acceptable, prevent submit event
    }
});
```

Also notice that you forgot some closing braces…

Comment: What does not work? Do you get any errors? Do some debugging, `console.log` some values. Did you complete the `$().ready` wrapper? What did you put in place of the `acceptable` comments?

Comment: ok got it to work. but when the form is submitted, the email address that is input cant seem to be recorded. please help

Comment: add my mail.php file above